# Why it could not find the main class?

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror, mainclass

I have a very simple code:

```
package mygame;
public class RunGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

I can compile that code but I cannot run it. When I type "java RunGame" in the command line I get:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   RunGame (wrong name: mygame/RunGame).
>   .... 
> Could not find the main class:
>   RunGame. Program will exit.

Comment: What command line are you using to run your class?

Comment: I tried to run the program with "java RunGame" and it was the mistake. I needed to use "java mygame.RunGame".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
java mygame.RunGame
```

is the java executable syntax. i.e, java classname.qualified.with.full.packaging

Also what is the RunColoredTrails class in the output you have shown?

Comment: It was a mistake. It should be "RunGame"

Answer (score 7):

u might be trying
`C:\your-java-directory-\mydir\> java RunGame` right ?

remember RunGame is inside a package called mydir.
so go one step back in ur execution path..

`c:\your-java-directory\>`

now compile and execute like this

`c:\your-java-directory\> javac mydir\RunGame.java`
`c:\your-java-directory\> java mydir.RunGame`